# Derived Column in SSIS - Trailing Space

Tags: sql, ssis, etl, removing-whitespace, derived-column

I have tried several ways to format a derived column to eliminate trailing spaces. To format the column when just viewing the column in Excel and transferring to Access was:

```
'=TRIM(CLEAN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,CHAR(160),"")))
```

In the derived column I've tried:

```
- REPLACE(RTRIM([Provider Number]),"\\x00A0","") == "" ? (DT_STR,10,1252)NULL(DT_STR,10,1252) : [Provider Number]

- TRIM([Provider Number]) == "" ? (DT_STR,10,1252)NULL(DT_STR,10,1252) : [Provider Number]

- LTRIM(RTRIM([Provider Number]))
```

When I query the length for the column my results still count 1 extra space when the package runs (successfully):

[image: Results]

Comment: Are you sure it's a space at the end of the line? The SSIS function `TRIM` [does not remove newlines and tabs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/trim-ssis-expression). To see what it is, try adding a "!" to the field in a Derived Column Transformation.

Comment: Would I put the "!" at the end of the first part of the formula?
TRIM([Provider Number]) == "" ? (DT_STR,10,1252)NULL(DT_STR,10,1252)! : [Provider Number]

Comment: No, you'd do this instead of the TRIM().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you know what you are trying to trim but you are having difficulty use ascii value in SSIS.

I can't seem to figure out how to use ASCII in SSIS however you can run it through a script component. Make sure you check on inputs that you want to Read/Write ProviderNumber.

simple code:

```
Row.ProviderNumber = Row.ProviderNumber.TrimEnd((char)160);
```

//Add .Trim() to clear all [white space](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t809ektx%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Added due to comment:

After you run it through C# then you can do your derived column

```
TRIM([Provider Number]) == "" ? NULL(DT_STR,10,1252) : [Provider Number]
```

TRIM might be excessive here, but doesn't really hurt.